# sqlite3 C API cant Open/Close more than 1024 database

Tags: c, optimization, sqlite, prepared-statement, limits

Yop, 
I have an application running continuesly  and needs to acess a sqlite3 database.
The program crash after about 1022 open/close of the same database.

Exemple:

```
int i = 1024;
sqlite3 * db;
while(i){

    sqlite3_open("database.sqlite",&db) ;
    // exécute prepared statement
    sqlite3_close(db);
    i--;

}
```

After 1022 iteration I cant open database, Iv Got the error:
**Failed to open database  unable to open database fileFailed to prepare database library routine called out of sequence2**

I take a look at the limits sqlite documentation but no mentions of such of limit:
http://sqlite.org/limits.html

Comment: Works for me. Can you share some additional information about your environment, such as sqlite version and OS you're running on.

Answer (score 1):

You're bumping into the `max open files per process` limit of the operating system itself.

Have a look at `ulimit -S -a`: (mine shown here for example)

```
xenon-lornix:~> ulimit -S -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 29567
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 29567
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Look through the list, see where it says `open files`?  The default limit is 1024, meaning that a user (you in this case!) may only have a maximum of 1024 files open per process at once.

A typical program has 3 files open by default, STDIN, STDOUT, & STDERR... leaving 1021 file descriptors available... so when you go to open the 1022nd database, it refuses, and fails.

Be sure to read the man page involving `ulimit`, surprisingly, it's NOT <strike>`man ulimit`</strike>!  Best documentation is in `bash`, so try `man bash`, then press slash ('`/`') and type `ulimit` to search for it. (Around line 3383 in my bash man page)

The more detailed programming side of the various ulimits can be found in `man getrlimit`.

Please remember that ulimit works with both **HARD** and **SOFT** limits.  A user can change their **SOFT** limit (via `-S`) from 0 to whatever the **HARD** (`-H`) limit value is.  But a user cannot **RAISE** their **HARD** limit, and if user **LOWERS** their **HARD** limit, they can't raise it back up again.  Only a super-user (root) may raise a **HARD** limit.

So to raise your **SOFT** `open files` limit, try this:

```
ulimit -S -n 8192
```

A quirk... ulimit **defaults** to setting **HARD** limits.  I have an alias for ulimit to default to the **soft** limit, like this:

```
alias ulimit='ulimit -S'
```

If you happen to add the `-H` option, it overrides the default **soft** (`-S`) option, so all is good.

To see your **hard** limits:

```
ulimit -H -a
```

Comment: Wait... you're closing the DB in the loop... weird.

Comment: Perusing the sqlite3 docs... it seems that the file __may__ not be closed immediately due to various factors, so it's quite possible that you're hitting the 1024 limit since the sqlite3 services have delayed the release of the file descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't `sqlite3_finalize` your prepared statements. You can't close a database that still has outstanding prepared statements. Do you check the result code of `sqlite3_close`?